# VB.NET: Using StreamWriter to write one line at a time

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, filesystems, streamwriter

Yeah, I've been trying to wrap my head around this but, I want to use a for loop to allow StreamWriter to write one line at a time; this is what i've come up with so far:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Module writeOneLineAtATime
    Sub Main()

    Dim fileWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim lineOfCode As String

    Dim fileName, filePath As String

    'Get that file location, dog.
    fileName = "someonewashere.txt"
    filePath = "Data\"

    Debug.Print("File location: " + filePath + fileName)

    fileWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filePath + fileName, True)


    Do
        fileWriter.WriteLine("2butt")
        fileWriter.Close()
    Loop


    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to do this which is as follows:

```
Dim fullyQualifiedPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)

Using sw As New StreamWriter(fullyQualifiedPath)
    sw.WriteLine("Line1")
    sw.WriteLine("Line2)
    ' etc.
End Using
```

Wrapping the code in a `Using` block means that you don't have to `Close` or `Dispose` of it when you are done as that is all taken care of.

Also using `Path.Combine` is safer than concatenating the path and file yourself, but anytime you are concatenating strings you should use `&` instead of `+`.